# How to run an autocomplete on an array with PHP, MySQL, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, autocomplete

I need to extract saved information from a database table with the autocomplete function on "N" number of entries. That is, in each entry of a new row, insert a new data and continue repeating said function (autocomplete).

**Example:** The information contained in the variable **availableTags** and **availableTags2** is the information I want to extract from the database table.

**What would the command for such a function look like?**

***index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    
    var availableTags2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskel","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme", "MySQL", "PostgreSQL"];

    $( ".tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: 'pl.php',
     select: function (event, ui) {
        var index = availableTags.indexOf(ui.item.value);
        $("#" + $(event.target).attr("data-target")).val(availableTags2[index]);  
    }
});
  } );

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<input class="tags" data-target="code1" name="name">
<label for="tags">Number:</label>
<input name="code" id="code1"><br><br>
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<input class="tags"  data-target="code2"  name="name">
<label for="tags">Number:</label>
<input name="code" id="code2"><br><br>
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<input class="tags"  data-target="code3"  name="name">
<label for="tags">Number:</label>
<input name="code" id="code3"><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***pl.php***

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    # conectare la base de datos
 include('./dbcontroller.php');
$db_handle = new DBController();

$return_arr = array();

$sqlc = "SELECT  * FROM pl WHERE availableTags like '%".$_GET['term']."%' LIMIT 5";

$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sqlc);

foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
/* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/       
    $row_array['value'] = $faq[$k]['availableTags'];
    $row_array['availableTags']=$faq[$k]['availableTags'];
    
    $row_array['availableTags']=$faq[$k]['availableTags'];
    $row_array['availableTags2']=$faq[$k]['availableTags2'];
    
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

***dbcontroller.php***

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "programming languages";
    
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }
    
    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }
    
    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
    function insertQuery($query) {
        mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
        return $insert_id;
    }
    
    function getIds($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row[0];
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
   function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}
?>
```

***programming languages.sql***

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 29-01-2023 a las 17:54:32
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.25-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.1.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `programming languages`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `pl`
--

CREATE TABLE `pl` (
  `availableTags` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `availableTags2` int(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pl`
--

INSERT INTO `pl` (`availableTags`, `availableTags2`) VALUES
('ActionScript', 1),
('AppleScript', 2),
('Asp', 3),
('BASIC', 4),
('C', 5),
('C++', 6),
('Clojure', 7),
('Cobol', 8),
('ColdFusion', 9),
('Erlang', 10),
('Fortran', 11),
('Groovy', 12),
('Haskel', 13),
('Java', 14),
('JavaScript', 15),
('Lisp', 16),
('Pearl', 17),
('PHP', 18),
('Python', 19),
('Ruby', 20),
('Scala', 21),
('Scheme', 22),
('MySQL', 23),
('PostgreSQL', 24);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Thanks.

**HERE MY PROBLEM**
When I extract the data from the variables **availableTags** and **availableTags2** in input, the corresponding number does not appear, only the name of the programming language.

[image: PROBLEM TO SOLVE.]

Comment: Please post your PHP code as code, and not as an image. Regarding your expected outcome - am I understanding correctly that you want to fill the inputs with pairs such as `1:ActionScript`, `2:AppleScript`, etc? If not, please edit your question, and add the outcome you expect. Be sure to post a specific example.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, Hi, how are you?. I hope all is well. Thanks for the observations, I already made the correction of the specifications that you mentioned. And the result that I expect, is exactly what you say. i want to fill the inputs with pairs such as
1:ActionScript.
2: AppleScript.
3:etc.

Comment: See if https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform.html-quickform-advcheckbox.phpworks for you.  If you like it, please report back.